# Fixed flexbox sidebar with scrollable content - no solutions work

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navigation, sidebar

I'm creating a basic webpage that will have a fixed sidebar and scrollable content area. Unfortunately, every single solution I've found

1. flat-out isn't working (meaning the sidebar sticks to the page and disappears as one scrolls down), or
2. cuts off the image container that holds [these two images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnraL.jpg) in place at the top of the main content area, plus everything above it.

Here's the codepen for the project: https://codepen.io/__JMar1/pen/jOYroOY

```css
div {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sitewrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Sidebar */

.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

.title-item {
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.side-spacer {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.side-item {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.rights {
  margin-top: 80px;
  max-width: 225px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: small;
  color: rgb(110, 110, 110);
}


/* Main Content Area */


/* Header to be used on all pages */

.header {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.imagecontainer-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.imagecontainer {
  max-height: 450px;
  max-width: 450px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!--- Head --->

<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>J.S. Marino</title>
</head>

<!--- Body --->

<body id="body">
  <div class="sitewrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="title-item">J.S. Marino</div>
      <div class="side-item">Writing</div>
      <div class="side-item">Photography</div>
      <div class="side-item">Eureka</div>
      <div class="side-spacer">&#8203;</div>
      <div class="side-item">About</div>
      <div class="side-item">Contact</div>
      <div class="rights">© 2020 - 2022 Jeremy Marino. All Rights Reserved.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="header">Test Page</div>
      <div class="imagecontainer-parent">
        <div class="imagecontainer">
          <img src="images/60362401_1407048259444464_8317741293019070464_n.jpg" alt="Blurry monochrome image of lonely workstation">
        </div>
        <div class="imagecontainer">
          <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="An ethereal waterfront">
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vix dolor dictas mnesarchum. Ad mel omnis debet. Utinam vituperatoribus quo at. Sit te solum oporteat, ad quaeque fierent nec. No minimum probatus qui. Tollit graece verterem mei ut, munere latine no vis, brute dolorem
        ancillae his cu. Nec vero nihil ut, usu vide accommodare no. Ne dicit nominati maiestatis usu, vis id amet definitiones. Cu sed brute scripserit, vidisse dolorem sea te, prima consulatu per ei. Ut quo discere vituperata argumentum, oportere adversarium
        eam ne. Mea munere denique voluptatum ea, et vidit graece inciderint nam. Mea ad audire concludaturque, mel eu aliquam corrumpit. Vim no probo errem fuisset. At primis blandit laboramus pro. Ad velit doming eam, fabulas tibique efficiantur cum
        no, deserunt explicari et eam. Simul homero pri ut. Vis ea tale autem lorem, vim ea regione atomorum constituto. Ei vix sapientem patrioque, mei omnesque pertinacia ad. Id cum error iudico, vis dicta ancillae definiebas et, eos ad euismod omittam.
        No sed meis torquatos, vel in tamquam luptatum, cu nulla mandamus his. Reque accumsan sententiae ius cu, eu nominavi appetere mea. Cu impetus diceret consequat nam, pro cu alterum periculis. Sonet vituperata te vis, ea quo nullam atomorum assueverit.
        Recusabo sententiae at vix. Duo autem simul oporteat ex, putent tritani ne quo. Ei inani commune reformidans eum, sonet putent noster eum ex, eam ne sumo eligendi tacimates. Dictas sanctus similique ad usu. Ea sint vidit tempor cum, mentitum electram
        imperdiet quo an. Enim officiis id mea. Rebum ignota eruditi mea ei. No nisl consequat cum. Mel cu malis etiam splendide, an veniam percipitur nam, dolore feugiat scripserit ex vis. Pro nonumy utroque in. Eos eu timeam mentitum insolens, sit viris
        euripidis dissentiet ad, usu ut alia possim luptatum. Facete aliquip petentium eam ad, ne est ferri clita putent. Vis munere mucius vivendum id. Quot complectitur et duo, te est aeterno fastidii incorrupte. Solum populo vix id, error probatus
        quaerendum mea at, choro invenire maiestatis ex mei. Ea nec graecis inciderint, populo pertinacia assueverit ne mel. Menandri partiendo te per. Cum no putant apeirian percipitur, habeo disputando pro ex. Eam equidem patrioque instructior ei, ea
        epicuri accusamus mel. In quo error oporteat consetetur. Mea te wisi cetero epicuri. Nec ei viris semper splendide. Sumo suscipiantur vim ea, ea sit accumsan tractatos adolescens. Vim ad autem signiferumque conclusionemque, et dico honestatis
        liberavisse his. Iusto melius concludaturque qui ei. His eu brute indoctum reprimique. Summo iudico tacimates eum et, per eu nihil diceret luptatum, mea latine inimicus evertitur ut. At quot phaedrum repudiare sea, mel et probo paulo disputationi,
        tota albucius eam ad. Malis sapientem his ea. Sea quis sonet audiam ut. Mea at paulo aliquid. Per ad veri impedit, harum exerci eligendi eu vim. Exerci graece temporibus ad vim, at quo apeirian patrioque efficiendi. No quo sapientem splendide
        deterruisset, qui quod omittantur ad. Qui an inani dicam fierent, voluptua gubergren in per. Vel ad munere impetus tincidunt, ea lorem prompta denique nam. Eu modus causae appetere his, quis ferri epicuri mei ea, vim ea eros inimicus moderatius.
        Ubique impetus interesset te sea. Ex exerci indoctum cum. Pri phaedrum dissentiunt cu, nonumy rationibus mel an. Mel ridens ornatus delicatissimi et, ignota delenit maiestatis ei vim. Clita alterum maiestatis vel et, nobis noluisse sententiae
        ut nam, no usu alii dolores conclusionemque. At decore option suscipit pro, an qui epicurei disputationi. Sit at viris facilis perpetua, eam nostrud facilisis ei. Te ius purto nihil facilisi, an vis utinam aliquam. Eum ad delenit intellegam, ius
        alii meis tacimates in. In eum amet fabellas. Ignota habemus no pro, ad purto labitur mea, te quaeque periculis eum. In eam veniam accumsan evertitur. At cum semper euismod, has et offendit sensibus, no summo tincidunt assueverit pro. Ut munere
        tritani democritum nec, amet natum salutatus eu sit. Ne usu modus omnium aliquam. Erant consequuntur no quo, nec in nihil nostro vituperata. Rationibus sadipscing signiferumque ne duo, te vis postulant consequat interpretaris, nominavi salutandi
        nam cu. No vim zril ignota, nam expetendis intellegam cu. Cum case malorum voluptatum an, te ornatus fabellas complectitur his. Vim lorem ponderum ex, affert albucius ius no. Nemore ancillae quo et. Et natum everti accusamus eam, mea fugit populo
        appetere ad. Eu ferri delicata eam, ea liber menandri antiopam mei, an singulis salutatus eam. Pro an errem simul, usu id elit tollit abhorreant. Veniam populo per et, sea in meis quando. Has suavitate maluisset ea. Modo case te vim, sit in facete
        feugiat pertinax, veri habeo at quo. Harum senserit sea ne, platonem sapientem ea vel. Vim admodum feugait perfecto ne, graeci audire te mei. Deserunt pericula mel ut, officiis neglegentur ius ea. Rebum eloquentiam contentiones cu sit, cu has
        possit temporibus, sed quem erat alterum ut. Id sea apeirian molestiae. Ea sed doctus omittam, hendrerit forensibus sed ut. Ne mazim deleniti vituperata eam, ex everti pertinacia eum. In erant dignissim vim, id pro quidam dolorum. Cu explicari
        vituperata cum. Incorrupte definitiones usu ad. Ex has assum sapientem intellegebat, mei mentitum delectus quaestio ea, quas augue bonorum an pri. An molestie necessitatibus sea, laboramus consectetuer vis id. Eu ius mutat brute, pri tacimates
        inimicus ne, delicata vulputate vituperatoribus et mel. Timeam bonorum no his.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vix dolor dictas mnesarchum. Ad mel omnis debet. Utinam vituperatoribus quo at. Sit te solum oporteat, ad quaeque fierent nec. No minimum
        probatus qui. Tollit graece verterem mei ut, munere latine no vis, brute dolorem ancillae his cu. Nec vero nihil ut, usu vide accommodare no. Ne dicit nominati maiestatis usu, vis id amet definitiones. Cu sed brute scripserit, vidisse dolorem
        sea te, prima consulatu per ei. Ut quo discere vituperata argumentum, oportere adversarium eam ne. Mea munere denique voluptatum ea, et vidit graece inciderint nam. Mea ad audire concludaturque, mel eu aliquam corrumpit. Vim no probo errem fuisset.
        At primis blandit laboramus pro. Ad velit doming eam, fabulas tibique efficiantur cum no, deserunt explicari et eam. Simul homero pri ut. Vis ea tale autem lorem, vim ea regione atomorum constituto. Ei vix sapientem patrioque, mei omnesque pertinacia
        ad. Id cum error iudico, vis dicta ancillae definiebas et, eos ad euismod omittam. No sed meis torquatos, vel in tamquam luptatum, cu nulla mandamus his. Reque accumsan sententiae ius cu, eu nominavi appetere mea. Cu impetus diceret consequat
        nam, pro cu alterum periculis. Sonet vituperata te vis, ea quo nullam atomorum assueverit. Recusabo sententiae at vix. Duo autem simul oporteat ex, putent tritani ne quo. Ei inani commune reformidans eum, sonet putent noster eum ex, eam ne sumo
        eligendi tacimates. Dictas sanctus similique ad usu. Ea sint vidit tempor cum, mentitum electram imperdiet quo an. Enim officiis id mea. Rebum ignota eruditi mea ei. No nisl consequat cum. Mel cu malis etiam splendide, an veniam percipitur nam,
        dolore feugiat scripserit ex vis. Pro nonumy utroque in. Eos eu timeam mentitum insolens, sit viris euripidis dissentiet ad, usu ut alia possim luptatum. Facete aliquip petentium eam ad, ne est ferri clita putent. Vis munere mucius vivendum id.
        Quot complectitur et duo, te est aeterno fastidii incorrupte. Solum populo vix id, error probatus quaerendum mea at, choro invenire maiestatis ex mei. Ea nec graecis inciderint, populo pertinacia assueverit ne mel. Menandri partiendo te per. Cum
        no putant apeirian percipitur, habeo disputando pro ex. Eam equidem patrioque instructior ei, ea epicuri accusamus mel. In quo error oporteat consetetur. Mea te wisi cetero epicuri. Nec ei viris semper splendide. Sumo suscipiantur vim ea, ea sit
        accumsan tractatos adolescens. Vim ad autem signiferumque conclusionemque, et dico honestatis liberavisse his. Iusto melius concludaturque qui ei. His eu brute indoctum reprimique. Summo iudico tacimates eum et, per eu nihil diceret luptatum,
        mea latine inimicus evertitur ut. At quot phaedrum repudiare sea, mel et probo paulo disputationi, tota albucius eam ad. Malis sapientem his ea. Sea quis sonet audiam ut. Mea at paulo aliquid. Per ad veri impedit, harum exerci eligendi eu vim.
        Exerci graece temporibus ad vim, at quo apeirian patrioque efficiendi. No quo sapientem splendide deterruisset, qui quod omittantur ad. Qui an inani dicam fierent, voluptua gubergren in per. Vel ad munere impetus tincidunt, ea lorem prompta denique
        nam. Eu modus causae appetere his, quis ferri epicuri mei ea, vim ea eros inimicus moderatius. Ubique impetus interesset te sea. Ex exerci indoctum cum. Pri phaedrum dissentiunt cu, nonumy rationibus mel an. Mel ridens ornatus delicatissimi et,
        ignota delenit maiestatis ei vim. Clita alterum maiestatis vel et, nobis noluisse sententiae ut nam, no usu alii dolores conclusionemque. At decore option suscipit pro, an qui epicurei disputationi. Sit at viris facilis perpetua, eam nostrud facilisis
        ei. Te ius purto nihil facilisi, an vis utinam aliquam. Eum ad delenit intellegam, ius alii meis tacimates in. In eum amet fabellas. Ignota habemus no pro, ad purto labitur mea, te quaeque periculis eum. In eam veniam accumsan evertitur. At cum
        semper euismod, has et offendit sensibus, no summo tincidunt assueverit pro. Ut munere tritani democritum nec, amet natum salutatus eu sit. Ne usu modus omnium aliquam. Erant consequuntur no quo, nec in nihil nostro vituperata. Rationibus sadipscing
        signiferumque ne duo, te vis postulant consequat interpretaris, nominavi salutandi nam cu. No vim zril ignota, nam expetendis intellegam cu. Cum case malorum voluptatum an, te ornatus fabellas complectitur his. Vim lorem ponderum ex, affert albucius
        ius no. Nemore ancillae quo et. Et natum everti accusamus eam, mea fugit populo appetere ad. Eu ferri delicata eam, ea liber menandri antiopam mei, an singulis salutatus eam. Pro an errem simul, usu id elit tollit abhorreant. Veniam populo per
        et, sea in meis quando. Has suavitate maluisset ea. Modo case te vim, sit in facete feugiat pertinax, veri habeo at quo. Harum senserit sea ne, platonem sapientem ea vel. Vim admodum feugait perfecto ne, graeci audire te mei. Deserunt pericula
        mel ut, officiis neglegentur ius ea. Rebum eloquentiam contentiones cu sit, cu has possit temporibus, sed quem erat alterum ut. Id sea apeirian molestiae. Ea sed doctus omittam, hendrerit forensibus sed ut. Ne mazim deleniti vituperata eam, ex
        everti pertinacia eum. In erant dignissim vim, id pro quidam dolorum. Cu explicari vituperata cum. Incorrupte definitiones usu ad. Ex has assum sapientem intellegebat, mei mentitum delectus quaestio ea, quas augue bonorum an pri. An molestie necessitatibus
        sea, laboramus consectetuer vis id. Eu ius mutat brute, pri tacimates inimicus ne, delicata vulputate vituperatoribus et mel. Timeam bonorum no his.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vix dolor dictas mnesarchum. Ad mel omnis debet. Utinam vituperatoribus
        quo at. Sit te solum oporteat, ad quaeque fierent nec. No minimum probatus qui. Tollit graece verterem mei ut, munere latine no vis, brute dolorem ancillae his cu. Nec vero nihil ut, usu vide accommodare no. Ne dicit nominati maiestatis usu, vis
        id amet definitiones. Cu sed brute scripserit, vidisse dolorem sea te, prima consulatu per ei. Ut quo discere vituperata argumentum, oportere adversarium eam ne. Mea munere denique voluptatum ea, et vidit graece inciderint nam. Mea ad audire concludaturque,
        mel eu aliquam corrumpit. Vim no probo errem fuisset. At primis blandit laboramus pro. Ad velit doming eam, fabulas tibique efficiantur cum no, deserunt explicari et eam. Simul homero pri ut. Vis ea tale autem lorem, vim ea regione atomorum constituto.
        Ei vix sapientem patrioque, mei omnesque pertinacia ad. Id cum error iudico, vis dicta ancillae definiebas et, eos ad euismod omittam. No sed meis torquatos, vel in tamquam luptatum, cu nulla mandamus his. Reque accumsan sententiae ius cu, eu
        nominavi appetere mea. Cu impetus diceret consequat nam, pro cu alterum periculis. Sonet vituperata te vis, ea quo nullam atomorum assueverit. Recusabo sententiae at vix. Duo autem simul oporteat ex, putent tritani ne quo. Ei inani commune reformidans
        eum, sonet putent noster eum ex, eam ne sumo eligendi tacimates. Dictas sanctus similique ad usu. Ea sint vidit tempor cum, mentitum electram imperdiet quo an. Enim officiis id mea. Rebum ignota eruditi mea ei. No nisl consequat cum. Mel cu malis
        etiam splendide, an veniam percipitur nam, dolore feugiat scripserit ex vis. Pro nonumy utroque in. Eos eu timeam mentitum insolens, sit viris euripidis dissentiet ad, usu ut alia possim luptatum. Facete aliquip petentium eam ad, ne est ferri
        clita putent. Vis munere mucius vivendum id. Quot complectitur et duo, te est aeterno fastidii incorrupte. Solum populo vix id, error probatus quaerendum mea at, choro invenire maiestatis ex mei. Ea nec graecis inciderint, populo pertinacia assueverit
        ne mel. Menandri partiendo te per. Cum no putant apeirian percipitur, habeo disputando pro ex. Eam equidem patrioque instructior ei, ea epicuri accusamus mel. In quo error oporteat consetetur. Mea te wisi cetero epicuri. Nec ei viris semper splendide.
        Sumo suscipiantur vim ea, ea sit accumsan tractatos adolescens. Vim ad autem signiferumque conclusionemque, et dico honestatis liberavisse his. Iusto melius concludaturque qui ei. His eu brute indoctum reprimique. Summo iudico tacimates eum et,
        per eu nihil diceret luptatum, mea latine inimicus evertitur ut. At quot phaedrum repudiare sea, mel et probo paulo disputationi, tota albucius eam ad. Malis sapientem his ea. Sea quis sonet audiam ut. Mea at paulo aliquid. Per ad veri impedit,
        harum exerci eligendi eu vim. Exerci graece temporibus ad vim, at quo apeirian patrioque efficiendi. No quo sapientem splendide deterruisset, qui quod omittantur ad. Qui an inani dicam fierent, voluptua gubergren in per. Vel ad munere impetus
        tincidunt, ea lorem prompta denique nam. Eu modus causae appetere his, quis ferri epicuri mei ea, vim ea eros inimicus moderatius. Ubique impetus interesset te sea. Ex exerci indoctum cum. Pri phaedrum dissentiunt cu, nonumy rationibus mel an.
        Mel ridens ornatus delicatissimi et, ignota delenit maiestatis ei vim. Clita alterum maiestatis vel et, nobis noluisse sententiae ut nam, no usu alii dolores conclusionemque. At decore option suscipit pro, an qui epicurei disputationi. Sit at
        viris facilis perpetua, eam nostrud facilisis ei. Te ius purto nihil facilisi, an vis utinam aliquam. Eum ad delenit intellegam, ius alii meis tacimates in. In eum amet fabellas. Ignota habemus no pro, ad purto labitur mea, te quaeque periculis
        eum. In eam veniam accumsan evertitur. At cum semper euismod, has et offendit sensibus, no summo tincidunt assueverit pro. Ut munere tritani democritum nec, amet natum salutatus eu sit. Ne usu modus omnium aliquam. Erant consequuntur no quo, nec
        in nihil nostro vituperata. Rationibus sadipscing signiferumque ne duo, te vis postulant consequat interpretaris, nominavi salutandi nam cu. No vim zril ignota, nam expetendis intellegam cu. Cum case malorum voluptatum an, te ornatus fabellas
        complectitur his. Vim lorem ponderum ex, affert albucius ius no. Nemore ancillae quo et. Et natum everti accusamus eam, mea fugit populo appetere ad. Eu ferri delicata eam, ea liber menandri antiopam mei, an singulis salutatus eam. Pro an errem
        simul, usu id elit tollit abhorreant. Veniam populo per et, sea in meis quando. Has suavitate maluisset ea. Modo case te vim, sit in facete feugiat pertinax, veri habeo at quo. Harum senserit sea ne, platonem sapientem ea vel. Vim admodum feugait
        perfecto ne, graeci audire te mei. Deserunt pericula mel ut, officiis neglegentur ius ea. Rebum eloquentiam contentiones cu sit, cu has possit temporibus, sed quem erat alterum ut. Id sea apeirian molestiae. Ea sed doctus omittam, hendrerit forensibus
        sed ut. Ne mazim deleniti vituperata eam, ex everti pertinacia eum. In erant dignissim vim, id pro quidam dolorum. Cu explicari vituperata cum. Incorrupte definitiones usu ad. Ex has assum sapientem intellegebat, mei mentitum delectus quaestio
        ea, quas augue bonorum an pri. An molestie necessitatibus sea, laboramus consectetuer vis id. Eu ius mutat brute, pri tacimates inimicus ne, delicata vulputate vituperatoribus et mel. Timeam bonorum no his.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions? Is there something fundamentally wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have to be heights defined. Use `position: sticky;` on the sidebar and define its height to `100%` so it takes up all space including the scroll.

I also did some other cleanup of the code. Using those additions/replacements is completely up to you.

See the changes made below:

```css
div {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sitewrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Sidebar */

.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%
}

.title-item {
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.side-spacer {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.side-item {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.rights {
  margin-top: 80px;
  max-width: 225px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: small;
  color: rgb(110, 110, 110);
}


/* Main Content Area */


/* Header to be used on all pages */

.header {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.imagecontainer-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.imagecontainer {
  max-height: 450px;
  max-width: 450px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!--- Head --->

<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>J.S. Marino</title>
</head>

<!--- Body --->

<body id="body">
  <div class="sitewrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="title-item">J.S. Marino</div>
      <div class="side-item">Writing</div>
      <div class="side-item">Photography</div>
      <div class="side-item">Eureka</div>
      <div class="side-spacer">&#8203;</div>
      <div class="side-item">About</div>
      <div class="side-item">Contact</div>
      <div class="rights">© 2020 - 2022 Jeremy Marino. All Rights Reserved.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="header">Test Page</div>
      <div class="imagecontainer-parent">
        <div class="imagecontainer">
          <img src="images/60362401_1407048259444464_8317741293019070464_n.jpg" alt="Blurry monochrome image of lonely workstation">
        </div>
        <div class="imagecontainer">
          <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="An ethereal waterfront">
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vix dolor dictas mnesarchum. Ad mel omnis debet. Utinam vituperatoribus quo at. Sit te solum oporteat, ad quaeque fierent nec. No minimum probatus qui. Tollit graece verterem mei ut, munere latine no vis, brute dolorem
        ancillae his cu. Nec vero nihil ut, usu vide accommodare no. Ne dicit nominati maiestatis usu, vis id amet definitiones. Cu sed brute scripserit, vidisse dolorem sea te, prima consulatu per ei. Ut quo discere vituperata argumentum, oportere adversarium
        eam ne. Mea munere denique voluptatum ea, et vidit graece inciderint nam. Mea ad audire concludaturque, mel eu aliquam corrumpit. Vim no probo errem fuisset. At primis blandit laboramus pro. Ad velit doming eam, fabulas tibique efficiantur cum
        no, deserunt explicari et eam. Simul homero pri ut. Vis ea tale autem lorem, vim ea regione atomorum constituto. Ei vix sapientem patrioque, mei omnesque pertinacia ad. Id cum error iudico, vis dicta ancillae definiebas et, eos ad euismod omittam.
        No sed meis torquatos, vel in tamquam luptatum, cu nulla mandamus his. Reque accumsan sententiae ius cu, eu nominavi appetere mea. Cu impetus diceret consequat nam, pro cu alterum periculis. Sonet vituperata te vis, ea quo nullam atomorum assueverit.
        Recusabo sententiae at vix. Duo autem simul oporteat ex, putent tritani ne quo. Ei inani commune reformidans eum, sonet putent noster eum ex, eam ne sumo eligendi tacimates. Dictas sanctus similique ad usu. Ea sint vidit tempor cum, mentitum electram
        imperdiet quo an. Enim officiis id mea. Rebum ignota eruditi mea ei. No nisl consequat cum. Mel cu malis etiam splendide, an veniam percipitur nam, dolore feugiat scripserit ex vis. Pro nonumy utroque in. Eos eu timeam mentitum insolens, sit viris
        euripidis dissentiet ad, usu ut alia possim luptatum. Facete aliquip petentium eam ad, ne est ferri clita putent. Vis munere mucius vivendum id. Quot complectitur et duo, te est aeterno fastidii incorrupte. Solum populo vix id, error probatus
        quaerendum mea at, choro invenire maiestatis ex mei. Ea nec graecis inciderint, populo pertinacia assueverit ne mel. Menandri partiendo te per. Cum no putant apeirian percipitur, habeo disputando pro ex. Eam equidem patrioque instructior ei, ea
        epicuri accusamus mel. In quo error oporteat consetetur. Mea te wisi cetero epicuri. Nec ei viris semper splendide. Sumo suscipiantur vim ea, ea sit accumsan tractatos adolescens. Vim ad autem signiferumque conclusionemque, et dico honestatis
        liberavisse his. Iusto melius concludaturque qui ei. His eu brute indoctum reprimique. Summo iudico tacimates eum et, per eu nihil diceret luptatum, mea latine inimicus evertitur ut. At quot phaedrum repudiare sea, mel et probo paulo disputationi,
        tota albucius eam ad. Malis sapientem his ea. Sea quis sonet audiam ut. Mea at paulo aliquid. Per ad veri impedit, harum exerci eligendi eu vim. Exerci graece temporibus ad vim, at quo apeirian patrioque efficiendi. No quo sapientem splendide
        deterruisset, qui quod omittantur ad. Qui an inani dicam fierent, voluptua gubergren in per. Vel ad munere impetus tincidunt, ea lorem prompta denique nam. Eu modus causae appetere his, quis ferri epicuri mei ea, vim ea eros inimicus moderatius.
        Ubique impetus interesset te sea. Ex exerci indoctum cum. Pri phaedrum dissentiunt cu, nonumy rationibus mel an. Mel ridens ornatus delicatissimi et, ignota delenit maiestatis ei vim. Clita alterum maiestatis vel et, nobis noluisse sententiae
        ut nam, no usu alii dolores conclusionemque. At decore option suscipit pro, an qui epicurei disputationi. Sit at viris facilis perpetua, eam nostrud facilisis ei. Te ius purto nihil facilisi, an vis utinam aliquam. Eum ad delenit intellegam, ius
        alii meis tacimates in. In eum amet fabellas. Ignota habemus no pro, ad purto labitur mea, te quaeque periculis eum. In eam veniam accumsan evertitur. At cum semper euismod, has et offendit sensibus, no summo tincidunt assueverit pro. Ut munere
        tritani democritum nec, amet natum salutatus eu sit. Ne usu modus omnium aliquam. Erant consequuntur no quo, nec in nihil nostro vituperata. Rationibus sadipscing signiferumque ne duo, te vis postulant consequat interpretaris, nominavi salutandi
        nam cu. No vim zril ignota, nam expetendis intellegam cu. Cum case malorum voluptatum an, te ornatus fabellas complectitur his. Vim lorem ponderum ex, affert albucius ius no. Nemore ancillae quo et. Et natum everti accusamus eam, mea fugit populo
        appetere ad. Eu ferri delicata eam, ea liber menandri antiopam mei, an singulis salutatus eam. Pro an errem simul, usu id elit tollit abhorreant. Veniam populo per et, sea in meis quando. Has suavitate maluisset ea. Modo case te vim, sit in facete
        feugiat pertinax, veri habeo at quo. Harum senserit sea ne, platonem sapientem ea vel. Vim admodum feugait perfecto ne, graeci audire te mei. Deserunt pericula mel ut, officiis neglegentur ius ea. Rebum eloquentiam contentiones cu sit, cu has
        possit temporibus, sed quem erat alterum ut. Id sea apeirian molestiae. Ea sed doctus omittam, hendrerit forensibus sed ut. Ne mazim deleniti vituperata eam, ex everti pertinacia eum. In erant dignissim vim, id pro quidam dolorum. Cu explicari
        vituperata cum. Incorrupte definitiones usu ad. Ex has assum sapientem intellegebat, mei mentitum delectus quaestio ea, quas augue bonorum an pri. An molestie necessitatibus sea, laboramus consectetuer vis id. Eu ius mutat brute, pri tacimates
        inimicus ne, delicata vulputate vituperatoribus et mel. Timeam bonorum no his.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vix dolor dictas mnesarchum. Ad mel omnis debet. Utinam vituperatoribus quo at. Sit te solum oporteat, ad quaeque fierent nec. No minimum
        probatus qui. Tollit graece verterem mei ut, munere latine no vis, brute dolorem ancillae his cu. Nec vero nihil ut, usu vide accommodare no. Ne dicit nominati maiestatis usu, vis id amet definitiones. Cu sed brute scripserit, vidisse dolorem
        sea te, prima consulatu per ei. Ut quo discere vituperata argumentum, oportere adversarium eam ne. Mea munere denique voluptatum ea, et vidit graece inciderint nam. Mea ad audire concludaturque, mel eu aliquam corrumpit. Vim no probo errem fuisset.
        At primis blandit laboramus pro. Ad velit doming eam, fabulas tibique efficiantur cum no, deserunt explicari et eam. Simul homero pri ut. Vis ea tale autem lorem, vim ea regione atomorum constituto. Ei vix sapientem patrioque, mei omnesque pertinacia
        ad. Id cum error iudico, vis dicta ancillae definiebas et, eos ad euismod omittam. No sed meis torquatos, vel in tamquam luptatum, cu nulla mandamus his. Reque accumsan sententiae ius cu, eu nominavi appetere mea. Cu impetus diceret consequat
        nam, pro cu alterum periculis. Sonet vituperata te vis, ea quo nullam atomorum assueverit. Recusabo sententiae at vix. Duo autem simul oporteat ex, putent tritani ne quo. Ei inani commune reformidans eum, sonet putent noster eum ex, eam ne sumo
        eligendi tacimates. Dictas sanctus similique ad usu. Ea sint vidit tempor cum, mentitum electram imperdiet quo an. Enim officiis id mea. Rebum ignota eruditi mea ei. No nisl consequat cum. Mel cu malis etiam splendide, an veniam percipitur nam,
        dolore feugiat scripserit ex vis. Pro nonumy utroque in. Eos eu timeam mentitum insolens, sit viris euripidis dissentiet ad, usu ut alia possim luptatum. Facete aliquip petentium eam ad, ne est ferri clita putent. Vis munere mucius vivendum id.
        Quot complectitur et duo, te est aeterno fastidii incorrupte. Solum populo vix id, error probatus quaerendum mea at, choro invenire maiestatis ex mei. Ea nec graecis inciderint, populo pertinacia assueverit ne mel. Menandri partiendo te per. Cum
        no putant apeirian percipitur, habeo disputando pro ex. Eam equidem patrioque instructior ei, ea epicuri accusamus mel. In quo error oporteat consetetur. Mea te wisi cetero epicuri. Nec ei viris semper splendide. Sumo suscipiantur vim ea, ea sit
        accumsan tractatos adolescens. Vim ad autem signiferumque conclusionemque, et dico honestatis liberavisse his. Iusto melius concludaturque qui ei. His eu brute indoctum reprimique. Summo iudico tacimates eum et, per eu nihil diceret luptatum,
        mea latine inimicus evertitur ut. At quot phaedrum repudiare sea, mel et probo paulo disputationi, tota albucius eam ad. Malis sapientem his ea. Sea quis sonet audiam ut. Mea at paulo aliquid. Per ad veri impedit, harum exerci eligendi eu vim.
        Exerci graece temporibus ad vim, at quo apeirian patrioque efficiendi. No quo sapientem splendide deterruisset, qui quod omittantur ad. Qui an inani dicam fierent, voluptua gubergren in per. Vel ad munere impetus tincidunt, ea lorem prompta denique
        nam. Eu modus causae appetere his, quis ferri epicuri mei ea, vim ea eros inimicus moderatius. Ubique impetus interesset te sea. Ex exerci indoctum cum. Pri phaedrum dissentiunt cu, nonumy rationibus mel an. Mel ridens ornatus delicatissimi et,
        ignota delenit maiestatis ei vim. Clita alterum maiestatis vel et, nobis noluisse sententiae ut nam, no usu alii dolores conclusionemque. At decore option suscipit pro, an qui epicurei disputationi. Sit at viris facilis perpetua, eam nostrud facilisis
        ei. Te ius purto nihil facilisi, an vis utinam aliquam. Eum ad delenit intellegam, ius alii meis tacimates in. In eum amet fabellas. Ignota habemus no pro, ad purto labitur mea, te quaeque periculis eum. In eam veniam accumsan evertitur. At cum
        semper euismod, has et offendit sensibus, no summo tincidunt assueverit pro. Ut munere tritani democritum nec, amet natum salutatus eu sit. Ne usu modus omnium aliquam. Erant consequuntur no quo, nec in nihil nostro vituperata. Rationibus sadipscing
        signiferumque ne duo, te vis postulant consequat interpretaris, nominavi salutandi nam cu. No vim zril ignota, nam expetendis intellegam cu. Cum case malorum voluptatum an, te ornatus fabellas complectitur his. Vim lorem ponderum ex, affert albucius
        ius no. Nemore ancillae quo et. Et natum everti accusamus eam, mea fugit populo appetere ad. Eu ferri delicata eam, ea liber menandri antiopam mei, an singulis salutatus eam. Pro an errem simul, usu id elit tollit abhorreant. Veniam populo per
        et, sea in meis quando. Has suavitate maluisset ea. Modo case te vim, sit in facete feugiat pertinax, veri habeo at quo. Harum senserit sea ne, platonem sapientem ea vel. Vim admodum feugait perfecto ne, graeci audire te mei. Deserunt pericula
        mel ut, officiis neglegentur ius ea. Rebum eloquentiam contentiones cu sit, cu has possit temporibus, sed quem erat alterum ut. Id sea apeirian molestiae. Ea sed doctus omittam, hendrerit forensibus sed ut. Ne mazim deleniti vituperata eam, ex
        everti pertinacia eum. In erant dignissim vim, id pro quidam dolorum. Cu explicari vituperata cum. Incorrupte definitiones usu ad. Ex has assum sapientem intellegebat, mei mentitum delectus quaestio ea, quas augue bonorum an pri. An molestie necessitatibus
        sea, laboramus consectetuer vis id. Eu ius mutat brute, pri tacimates inimicus ne, delicata vulputate vituperatoribus et mel. Timeam bonorum no his.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vix dolor dictas mnesarchum. Ad mel omnis debet. Utinam vituperatoribus
        quo at. Sit te solum oporteat, ad quaeque fierent nec. No minimum probatus qui. Tollit graece verterem mei ut, munere latine no vis, brute dolorem ancillae his cu. Nec vero nihil ut, usu vide accommodare no. Ne dicit nominati maiestatis usu, vis
        id amet definitiones. Cu sed brute scripserit, vidisse dolorem sea te, prima consulatu per ei. Ut quo discere vituperata argumentum, oportere adversarium eam ne. Mea munere denique voluptatum ea, et vidit graece inciderint nam. Mea ad audire concludaturque,
        mel eu aliquam corrumpit. Vim no probo errem fuisset. At primis blandit laboramus pro. Ad velit doming eam, fabulas tibique efficiantur cum no, deserunt explicari et eam. Simul homero pri ut. Vis ea tale autem lorem, vim ea regione atomorum constituto.
        Ei vix sapientem patrioque, mei omnesque pertinacia ad. Id cum error iudico, vis dicta ancillae definiebas et, eos ad euismod omittam. No sed meis torquatos, vel in tamquam luptatum, cu nulla mandamus his. Reque accumsan sententiae ius cu, eu
        nominavi appetere mea. Cu impetus diceret consequat nam, pro cu alterum periculis. Sonet vituperata te vis, ea quo nullam atomorum assueverit. Recusabo sententiae at vix. Duo autem simul oporteat ex, putent tritani ne quo. Ei inani commune reformidans
        eum, sonet putent noster eum ex, eam ne sumo eligendi tacimates. Dictas sanctus similique ad usu. Ea sint vidit tempor cum, mentitum electram imperdiet quo an. Enim officiis id mea. Rebum ignota eruditi mea ei. No nisl consequat cum. Mel cu malis
        etiam splendide, an veniam percipitur nam, dolore feugiat scripserit ex vis. Pro nonumy utroque in. Eos eu timeam mentitum insolens, sit viris euripidis dissentiet ad, usu ut alia possim luptatum. Facete aliquip petentium eam ad, ne est ferri
        clita putent. Vis munere mucius vivendum id. Quot complectitur et duo, te est aeterno fastidii incorrupte. Solum populo vix id, error probatus quaerendum mea at, choro invenire maiestatis ex mei. Ea nec graecis inciderint, populo pertinacia assueverit
        ne mel. Menandri partiendo te per. Cum no putant apeirian percipitur, habeo disputando pro ex. Eam equidem patrioque instructior ei, ea epicuri accusamus mel. In quo error oporteat consetetur. Mea te wisi cetero epicuri. Nec ei viris semper splendide.
        Sumo suscipiantur vim ea, ea sit accumsan tractatos adolescens. Vim ad autem signiferumque conclusionemque, et dico honestatis liberavisse his. Iusto melius concludaturque qui ei. His eu brute indoctum reprimique. Summo iudico tacimates eum et,
        per eu nihil diceret luptatum, mea latine inimicus evertitur ut. At quot phaedrum repudiare sea, mel et probo paulo disputationi, tota albucius eam ad. Malis sapientem his ea. Sea quis sonet audiam ut. Mea at paulo aliquid. Per ad veri impedit,
        harum exerci eligendi eu vim. Exerci graece temporibus ad vim, at quo apeirian patrioque efficiendi. No quo sapientem splendide deterruisset, qui quod omittantur ad. Qui an inani dicam fierent, voluptua gubergren in per. Vel ad munere impetus
        tincidunt, ea lorem prompta denique nam. Eu modus causae appetere his, quis ferri epicuri mei ea, vim ea eros inimicus moderatius. Ubique impetus interesset te sea. Ex exerci indoctum cum. Pri phaedrum dissentiunt cu, nonumy rationibus mel an.
        Mel ridens ornatus delicatissimi et, ignota delenit maiestatis ei vim. Clita alterum maiestatis vel et, nobis noluisse sententiae ut nam, no usu alii dolores conclusionemque. At decore option suscipit pro, an qui epicurei disputationi. Sit at
        viris facilis perpetua, eam nostrud facilisis ei. Te ius purto nihil facilisi, an vis utinam aliquam. Eum ad delenit intellegam, ius alii meis tacimates in. In eum amet fabellas. Ignota habemus no pro, ad purto labitur mea, te quaeque periculis
        eum. In eam veniam accumsan evertitur. At cum semper euismod, has et offendit sensibus, no summo tincidunt assueverit pro. Ut munere tritani democritum nec, amet natum salutatus eu sit. Ne usu modus omnium aliquam. Erant consequuntur no quo, nec
        in nihil nostro vituperata. Rationibus sadipscing signiferumque ne duo, te vis postulant consequat interpretaris, nominavi salutandi nam cu. No vim zril ignota, nam expetendis intellegam cu. Cum case malorum voluptatum an, te ornatus fabellas
        complectitur his. Vim lorem ponderum ex, affert albucius ius no. Nemore ancillae quo et. Et natum everti accusamus eam, mea fugit populo appetere ad. Eu ferri delicata eam, ea liber menandri antiopam mei, an singulis salutatus eam. Pro an errem
        simul, usu id elit tollit abhorreant. Veniam populo per et, sea in meis quando. Has suavitate maluisset ea. Modo case te vim, sit in facete feugiat pertinax, veri habeo at quo. Harum senserit sea ne, platonem sapientem ea vel. Vim admodum feugait
        perfecto ne, graeci audire te mei. Deserunt pericula mel ut, officiis neglegentur ius ea. Rebum eloquentiam contentiones cu sit, cu has possit temporibus, sed quem erat alterum ut. Id sea apeirian molestiae. Ea sed doctus omittam, hendrerit forensibus
        sed ut. Ne mazim deleniti vituperata eam, ex everti pertinacia eum. In erant dignissim vim, id pro quidam dolorum. Cu explicari vituperata cum. Incorrupte definitiones usu ad. Ex has assum sapientem intellegebat, mei mentitum delectus quaestio
        ea, quas augue bonorum an pri. An molestie necessitatibus sea, laboramus consectetuer vis id. Eu ius mutat brute, pri tacimates inimicus ne, delicata vulputate vituperatoribus et mel. Timeam bonorum no his.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you. And, yes, this code is certainly cleaner. I see what you've done and it makes sense. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have an element on fixed his **parent** should be on **relative** otherwise there could be strange behavior in the future, I changed your code now it should work, I put your sidebar inside another div and set it in **position relative** then I set the sidebar in **fixed** and said to the main content to have a **width of fit-content** but you can change this to your needs all you have to do now is to change the width of **sidebar-wrapper (the div I created)** and the **width of main content**

```css
.sitewrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Sidebar */

.sidebar-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}
.rights {
   margin-top: 80px;
   max-width: 225px;
   line-height: 25px;
   font-size: small;
   color: rgb(110, 110, 110);
}


/* Main Content Area */


.main-container {
  width: fit-content // or % value or -webkit-fill-available
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!--- Body --->

<body id="body">
  <div class="sitewrapper">
   <div class="sidebar-wrapper"> <!--added by me -->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="title-item">J.S. Marino</div>
      <div class="side-item">Writing</div>
      <div class="side-item">Photography</div>
      <div class="side-item">Eureka</div>
      <div class="side-spacer">&#8203;</div>
      <div class="side-item">About</div>
      <div class="side-item">Contact</div>
      <div class="rights">© 2020 - 2022 Jeremy Marino. All Rights Reserved.</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="header">Test Page</div>
      <div class="imagecontainer-parent">
        <div class="imagecontainer">
          <img src="images/60362401_1407048259444464_8317741293019070464_n.jpg" alt="Blurry monochrome image of lonely workstation">
        </div>
        <div class="imagecontainer">
          <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="An ethereal waterfront">
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vix dolor dictas mnesarchum. Ad mel omnis debet. Utinam vituperatoribus quo at. Sit te solum oporteat, ad quaeque fierent nec. No minimum probatus qui. Tollit graece verterem mei ut, munere latine no vis, brute dolorem
        ancillae his cu. Nec vero nihil ut, usu vide accommodare no. Ne dicit nominati maiestatis usu, vis id amet definitiones. Cu sed brute scripserit, vidisse dolorem sea te, prima consulatu per ei. Ut quo discere vituperata argumentum, oportere adversarium
        eam ne. Mea munere denique voluptatum ea, et vidit graece inciderint nam. Mea ad audire concludaturque, mel eu aliquam corrumpit. Vim no probo errem fuisset. At primis blandit laboramus pro. Ad velit doming eam, fabulas tibique efficiantur cum
        no, deserunt explicari et eam. Simul homero pri ut. Vis ea tale autem lorem, vim ea regione atomorum constituto. Ei vix sapientem patrioque, mei omnesque pertinacia ad. Id cum error iudico, vis dicta ancillae definiebas et, eos ad euismod omittam.
        No sed meis torquatos, vel in tamquam luptatum, cu nulla mandamus his. Reque accumsan sententiae ius cu, eu nominavi appetere mea. Cu impetus diceret consequat nam, pro cu alterum periculis. Sonet vituperata te vis, ea quo nullam atomorum assueverit.
        Recusabo sententiae at vix. Duo autem simul oporteat ex, putent tritani ne quo. Ei inani commune reformidans eum, sonet putent noster eum ex, eam ne sumo eligendi tacimates. Dictas sanctus similique ad usu. Ea sint vidit tempor cum, mentitum electram
        imperdiet quo an. Enim officiis id mea. Rebum ignota eruditi mea ei. No nisl consequat cum. Mel cu malis etiam splendide, an veniam percipitur nam, dolore feugiat scripserit ex vis. Pro nonumy utroque in. Eos eu timeam mentitum insolens, sit viris
        euripidis dissentiet ad, usu ut alia possim luptatum. Facete aliquip petentium eam ad, ne est ferri clita putent. Vis munere mucius vivendum id. Quot complectitur et duo, te est aeterno fastidii incorrupte. Solum populo vix id, error probatus
        quaerendum mea at, choro invenire maiestatis ex mei. Ea nec graecis inciderint, populo pertinacia assueverit ne mel. Menandri partiendo te per. Cum no putant apeirian percipitur, habeo disputando pro ex. Eam equidem patrioque instructior ei, ea
        epicuri accusamus mel. In quo error oporteat consetetur. Mea te wisi cetero epicuri. Nec ei viris semper splendide. Sumo suscipiantur vim ea, ea sit accumsan tractatos adolescens. Vim ad autem signiferumque conclusionemque, et dico honestatis
        liberavisse his. Iusto melius concludaturque qui ei. His eu brute indoctum reprimique. Summo iudico tacimates eum et, per eu nihil diceret luptatum, mea latine inimicus evertitur ut. At quot phaedrum repudiare sea, mel et probo paulo disputationi,
        tota albucius eam ad. Malis sapientem his ea. Sea quis sonet audiam ut. Mea at paulo aliquid. Per ad veri impedit, harum exerci eligendi eu vim. Exerci graece temporibus ad vim, at quo apeirian patrioque efficiendi. No quo sapientem splendide
        deterruisset, qui quod omittantur ad. Qui an inani dicam fierent, voluptua gubergren in per. Vel ad munere impetus tincidunt, ea lorem prompta denique nam. Eu modus causae appetere his, quis ferri epicuri mei ea, vim ea eros inimicus moderatius.
        Ubique impetus interesset te sea. Ex exerci indoctum cum. Pri phaedrum dissentiunt cu, nonumy rationibus mel an. Mel ridens ornatus delicatissimi et, ignota delenit maiestatis ei vim. Clita alterum maiestatis vel et, nobis noluisse sententiae
        ut nam, no usu alii dolores conclusionemque. At decore option suscipit pro, an qui epicurei disputationi. Sit at viris facilis perpetua, eam nostrud facilisis ei. Te ius purto nihil facilisi, an vis utinam aliquam. Eum ad delenit intellegam, ius
        alii meis tacimates in. In eum amet fabellas. Ignota habemus no pro, ad purto labitur mea, te quaeque periculis eum. In eam veniam accumsan evertitur. At cum semper euismod, has et offendit sensibus, no summo tincidunt assueverit pro. Ut munere
        tritani democritum nec, amet natum salutatus eu sit. Ne usu modus omnium aliquam. Erant consequuntur no quo, nec in nihil nostro vituperata. Rationibus sadipscing signiferumque ne duo, te vis postulant consequat interpretaris, nominavi salutandi
        nam cu. No vim zril ignota, nam expetendis intellegam cu. Cum case malorum voluptatum an, te ornatus fabellas complectitur his. Vim lorem ponderum ex, affert albucius ius no. Nemore ancillae quo et. Et natum everti accusamus eam, mea fugit populo
        appetere ad. Eu ferri delicata eam, ea liber menandri antiopam mei, an singulis salutatus eam. Pro an errem simul, usu id elit tollit abhorreant. Veniam populo per et, sea in meis quando. Has suavitate maluisset ea. Modo case te vim, sit in facete
        feugiat pertinax, veri habeo at quo. Harum senserit sea ne, platonem sapientem ea vel. Vim admodum feugait perfecto ne, graeci audire te mei. Deserunt pericula mel ut, officiis neglegentur ius ea. Rebum eloquentiam contentiones cu sit, cu has
        possit temporibus, sed quem erat alterum ut. Id sea apeirian molestiae. Ea sed doctus omittam, hendrerit forensibus sed ut. Ne mazim deleniti vituperata eam, ex everti pertinacia eum. In erant dignissim vim, id pro quidam dolorum. Cu explicari
        vituperata cum. Incorrupte definitiones usu ad. Ex has assum sapientem intellegebat, mei mentitum delectus quaestio ea, quas augue bonorum an pri. An molestie necessitatibus sea, laboramus consectetuer vis id. Eu ius mutat brute, pri tacimates
        inimicus ne, delicata vulputate vituperatoribus et mel. Timeam bonorum no his.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vix dolor dictas mnesarchum. Ad mel omnis debet. Utinam vituperatoribus quo at. Sit te solum oporteat, ad quaeque fierent nec. No minimum
        probatus qui. Tollit graece verterem mei ut, munere latine no vis, brute dolorem ancillae his cu. Nec vero nihil ut, usu vide accommodare no. Ne dicit nominati maiestatis usu, vis id amet definitiones. Cu sed brute scripserit, vidisse dolorem
        sea te, prima consulatu per ei. Ut quo discere vituperata argumentum, oportere adversarium eam ne. Mea munere denique voluptatum ea, et vidit graece inciderint nam. Mea ad audire concludaturque, mel eu aliquam corrumpit. Vim no probo errem fuisset.
        At primis blandit laboramus pro. Ad velit doming eam, fabulas tibique efficiantur cum no, deserunt explicari et eam. Simul homero pri ut. Vis ea tale autem lorem, vim ea regione atomorum constituto. Ei vix sapientem patrioque, mei omnesque pertinacia
        ad. Id cum error iudico, vis dicta ancillae definiebas et, eos ad euismod omittam. No sed meis torquatos, vel in tamquam luptatum, cu nulla mandamus his. Reque accumsan sententiae ius cu, eu nominavi appetere mea. Cu impetus diceret consequat
        nam, pro cu alterum periculis. Sonet vituperata te vis, ea quo nullam atomorum assueverit. Recusabo sententiae at vix. Duo autem simul oporteat ex, putent tritani ne quo. Ei inani commune reformidans eum, sonet putent noster eum ex, eam ne sumo
        eligendi tacimates. Dictas sanctus similique ad usu. Ea sint vidit tempor cum, mentitum electram imperdiet quo an. Enim officiis id mea. Rebum ignota eruditi mea ei. No nisl consequat cum. Mel cu malis etiam splendide, an veniam percipitur nam,
        dolore feugiat scripserit ex vis. Pro nonumy utroque in. Eos eu timeam mentitum insolens, sit viris euripidis dissentiet ad, usu ut alia possim luptatum. Facete aliquip petentium eam ad, ne est ferri clita putent. Vis munere mucius vivendum id.
        Quot complectitur et duo, te est aeterno fastidii incorrupte. Solum populo vix id, error probatus quaerendum mea at, choro invenire maiestatis ex mei. Ea nec graecis inciderint, populo pertinacia assueverit ne mel. Menandri partiendo te per. Cum
        no putant apeirian percipitur, habeo disputando pro ex. Eam equidem patrioque instructior ei, ea epicuri accusamus mel. In quo error oporteat consetetur. Mea te wisi cetero epicuri. Nec ei viris semper splendide. Sumo suscipiantur vim ea, ea sit
        accumsan tractatos adolescens. Vim ad autem signiferumque conclusionemque, et dico honestatis liberavisse his. Iusto melius concludaturque qui ei. His eu brute indoctum reprimique. Summo iudico tacimates eum et, per eu nihil diceret luptatum,
        mea latine inimicus evertitur ut. At quot phaedrum repudiare sea, mel et probo paulo disputationi, tota albucius eam ad. Malis sapientem his ea. Sea quis sonet audiam ut. Mea at paulo aliquid. Per ad veri impedit, harum exerci eligendi eu vim.
        Exerci graece temporibus ad vim, at quo apeirian patrioque efficiendi. No quo sapientem splendide deterruisset, qui quod omittantur ad. Qui an inani dicam fierent, voluptua gubergren in per. Vel ad munere impetus tincidunt, ea lorem prompta denique
        nam. Eu modus causae appetere his, quis ferri epicuri mei ea, vim ea eros inimicus moderatius. Ubique impetus interesset te sea. Ex exerci indoctum cum. Pri phaedrum dissentiunt cu, nonumy rationibus mel an. Mel ridens ornatus delicatissimi et,
        ignota delenit maiestatis ei vim. Clita alterum maiestatis vel et, nobis noluisse sententiae ut nam, no usu alii dolores conclusionemque. At decore option suscipit pro, an qui epicurei disputationi. Sit at viris facilis perpetua, eam nostrud facilisis
        ei. Te ius purto nihil facilisi, an vis utinam aliquam. Eum ad delenit intellegam, ius alii meis tacimates in. In eum amet fabellas. Ignota habemus no pro, ad purto labitur mea, te quaeque periculis eum. In eam veniam accumsan evertitur. At cum
        semper euismod, has et offendit sensibus, no summo tincidunt assueverit pro. Ut munere tritani democritum nec, amet natum salutatus eu sit. Ne usu modus omnium aliquam. Erant consequuntur no quo, nec in nihil nostro vituperata. Rationibus sadipscing
        signiferumque ne duo, te vis postulant consequat interpretaris, nominavi salutandi nam cu. No vim zril ignota, nam expetendis intellegam cu. Cum case malorum voluptatum an, te ornatus fabellas complectitur his. Vim lorem ponderum ex, affert albucius
        ius no. Nemore ancillae quo et. Et natum everti accusamus eam, mea fugit populo appetere ad. Eu ferri delicata eam, ea liber menandri antiopam mei, an singulis salutatus eam. Pro an errem simul, usu id elit tollit abhorreant. Veniam populo per
        et, sea in meis quando. Has suavitate maluisset ea. Modo case te vim, sit in facete feugiat pertinax, veri habeo at quo. Harum senserit sea ne, platonem sapientem ea vel. Vim admodum feugait perfecto ne, graeci audire te mei. Deserunt pericula
        mel ut, officiis neglegentur ius ea. Rebum eloquentiam contentiones cu sit, cu has possit temporibus, sed quem erat alterum ut. Id sea apeirian molestiae. Ea sed doctus omittam, hendrerit forensibus sed ut. Ne mazim deleniti vituperata eam, ex
        everti pertinacia eum. In erant dignissim vim, id pro quidam dolorum. Cu explicari vituperata cum. Incorrupte definitiones usu ad. Ex has assum sapientem intellegebat, mei mentitum delectus quaestio ea, quas augue bonorum an pri. An molestie necessitatibus
        sea, laboramus consectetuer vis id. Eu ius mutat brute, pri tacimates inimicus ne, delicata vulputate vituperatoribus et mel. Timeam bonorum no his.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea vix dolor dictas mnesarchum. Ad mel omnis debet. Utinam vituperatoribus
        quo at. Sit te solum oporteat, ad quaeque fierent nec. No minimum probatus qui. Tollit graece verterem mei ut, munere latine no vis, brute dolorem ancillae his cu. Nec vero nihil ut, usu vide accommodare no. Ne dicit nominati maiestatis usu, vis
        id amet definitiones. Cu sed brute scripserit, vidisse dolorem sea te, prima consulatu per ei. Ut quo discere vituperata argumentum, oportere adversarium eam ne. Mea munere denique voluptatum ea, et vidit graece inciderint nam. Mea ad audire concludaturque,
        mel eu aliquam corrumpit. Vim no probo errem fuisset. At primis blandit laboramus pro. Ad velit doming eam, fabulas tibique efficiantur cum no, deserunt explicari et eam. Simul homero pri ut. Vis ea tale autem lorem, vim ea regione atomorum constituto.
        Ei vix sapientem patrioque, mei omnesque pertinacia ad. Id cum error iudico, vis dicta ancillae definiebas et, eos ad euismod omittam. No sed meis torquatos, vel in tamquam luptatum, cu nulla mandamus his. Reque accumsan sententiae ius cu, eu
        nominavi appetere mea. Cu impetus diceret consequat nam, pro cu alterum periculis. Sonet vituperata te vis, ea quo nullam atomorum assueverit. Recusabo sententiae at vix. Duo autem simul oporteat ex, putent tritani ne quo. Ei inani commune reformidans
        eum, sonet putent noster eum ex, eam ne sumo eligendi tacimates. Dictas sanctus similique ad usu. Ea sint vidit tempor cum, mentitum electram imperdiet quo an. Enim officiis id mea. Rebum ignota eruditi mea ei. No nisl consequat cum. Mel cu malis
        etiam splendide, an veniam percipitur nam, dolore feugiat scripserit ex vis. Pro nonumy utroque in. Eos eu timeam mentitum insolens, sit viris euripidis dissentiet ad, usu ut alia possim luptatum. Facete aliquip petentium eam ad, ne est ferri
        clita putent. Vis munere mucius vivendum id. Quot complectitur et duo, te est aeterno fastidii incorrupte. Solum populo vix id, error probatus quaerendum mea at, choro invenire maiestatis ex mei. Ea nec graecis inciderint, populo pertinacia assueverit
        ne mel. Menandri partiendo te per. Cum no putant apeirian percipitur, habeo disputando pro ex. Eam equidem patrioque instructior ei, ea epicuri accusamus mel. In quo error oporteat consetetur. Mea te wisi cetero epicuri. Nec ei viris semper splendide.
        Sumo suscipiantur vim ea, ea sit accumsan tractatos adolescens. Vim ad autem signiferumque conclusionemque, et dico honestatis liberavisse his. Iusto melius concludaturque qui ei. His eu brute indoctum reprimique. Summo iudico tacimates eum et,
        per eu nihil diceret luptatum, mea latine inimicus evertitur ut. At quot phaedrum repudiare sea, mel et probo paulo disputationi, tota albucius eam ad. Malis sapientem his ea. Sea quis sonet audiam ut. Mea at paulo aliquid. Per ad veri impedit,
        harum exerci eligendi eu vim. Exerci graece temporibus ad vim, at quo apeirian patrioque efficiendi. No quo sapientem splendide deterruisset, qui quod omittantur ad. Qui an inani dicam fierent, voluptua gubergren in per. Vel ad munere impetus
        tincidunt, ea lorem prompta denique nam. Eu modus causae appetere his, quis ferri epicuri mei ea, vim ea eros inimicus moderatius. Ubique impetus interesset te sea. Ex exerci indoctum cum. Pri phaedrum dissentiunt cu, nonumy rationibus mel an.
        Mel ridens ornatus delicatissimi et, ignota delenit maiestatis ei vim. Clita alterum maiestatis vel et, nobis noluisse sententiae ut nam, no usu alii dolores conclusionemque. At decore option suscipit pro, an qui epicurei disputationi. Sit at
        viris facilis perpetua, eam nostrud facilisis ei. Te ius purto nihil facilisi, an vis utinam aliquam. Eum ad delenit intellegam, ius alii meis tacimates in. In eum amet fabellas. Ignota habemus no pro, ad purto labitur mea, te quaeque periculis
        eum. In eam veniam accumsan evertitur. At cum semper euismod, has et offendit sensibus, no summo tincidunt assueverit pro. Ut munere tritani democritum nec, amet natum salutatus eu sit. Ne usu modus omnium aliquam. Erant consequuntur no quo, nec
        in nihil nostro vituperata. Rationibus sadipscing signiferumque ne duo, te vis postulant consequat interpretaris, nominavi salutandi nam cu. No vim zril ignota, nam expetendis intellegam cu. Cum case malorum voluptatum an, te ornatus fabellas
        complectitur his. Vim lorem ponderum ex, affert albucius ius no. Nemore ancillae quo et. Et natum everti accusamus eam, mea fugit populo appetere ad. Eu ferri delicata eam, ea liber menandri antiopam mei, an singulis salutatus eam. Pro an errem
        simul, usu id elit tollit abhorreant. Veniam populo per et, sea in meis quando. Has suavitate maluisset ea. Modo case te vim, sit in facete feugiat pertinax, veri habeo at quo. Harum senserit sea ne, platonem sapientem ea vel. Vim admodum feugait
        perfecto ne, graeci audire te mei. Deserunt pericula mel ut, officiis neglegentur ius ea. Rebum eloquentiam contentiones cu sit, cu has possit temporibus, sed quem erat alterum ut. Id sea apeirian molestiae. Ea sed doctus omittam, hendrerit forensibus
        sed ut. Ne mazim deleniti vituperata eam, ex everti pertinacia eum. In erant dignissim vim, id pro quidam dolorum. Cu explicari vituperata cum. Incorrupte definitiones usu ad. Ex has assum sapientem intellegebat, mei mentitum delectus quaestio
        ea, quas augue bonorum an pri. An molestie necessitatibus sea, laboramus consectetuer vis id. Eu ius mutat brute, pri tacimates inimicus ne, delicata vulputate vituperatoribus et mel. Timeam bonorum no his.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This causes an overflow on the x-axis on smaller devices.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this style to your sidebar:

```
position:fixed;
left: 0; // plus additional margin
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work at all. This is the result of that:

https://imgur.com/ZEUPJrw